# How to filter ng-repeat by a nested object's property

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following array:

```
  var boofers = [
    {
        "id" : "kurfki8z6786",
        "query" : {"name": "foo", "status": "open"},
        "uid" : "1416422209395",
    },
    {
        "id" : "kurfki8z6874",
        "query" : {"name": "puff", "status": "closed"},
        "uid" : "1416422209387",
    },
    {
        "id" : "kurfki8z6123",
        "query" : {"name": "joe", "status": "closed"},
        "uid" : "1416422209301",
    }
  ]
```

I need to print the `uid` values of `boofers` for the `status` of query in `boofer` objects to be `closed`, so I am trying the following but not getting the result as nothing gets printed for `{{boofer.uid}}`:

```
<div ng-repeat="boofer in boofers | filter: {query.status: 'closed'}">{{boofer.uid}}</div>
```

Could somebody tell me the mistake I am committing here and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `)` from each `id` in the JSON array:

```
boofers = [
    {
        "id" : "kurfki8z6786",
        "query" : {"name": "foo", "status": "open"},
        "uid" : "1416422209395",
    },
    {
        "id" : "kurfki8z6874",
        "query" : {"name": "puff", "status": "closed"},
        "uid" : "1416422209387",
    },
    {
        "id" : "kurfki8z6123",
        "query" : {"name": "joe", "status": "closed"},
        "uid" : "1416422209301",
    }
  ];
```

here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nk5Loxoy/

**NOTE**: If you are using an array in the query as before the edit, you should use a custom filter

Comment: @Micheal Zucchetta: Sorry, that was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: @Micheal Zucchetta: I am failing to understand why is it not working in my case. I am basically populating the `query` object from MongoDB using Mongoose with `.populate('query')`. I see no error when I try the same method to filter the way u've shown in the jsfiddle but I see no output, but I don't see any output either.

Comment: @Micheal Zucchetta: I have to go dirty and do `boofer in boofers | filter: 'closed'` for now to get things working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-if?

```
<div ng-repeat="boofer in boofers" ng-if="boofer.query.status==='closed'">{{boofer.uid}}</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I mistakenly had the nested `query` object to be an array whereas it was just an object. Could you please look at the post again and answer. Thank you.

Comment: The `filter: {boofer.query.status: 'closed'}` is not working with the updated post. I don't get any errors but I also don't get `{{boofer.uid}}` printed.